# difference between src_model and binding_model in Odoo13?

Tags: report, wizard, odoo-13

I want to know the difference between src_model and binding_model in odoo 13 in linkng a wizard/report if there is a difference??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syed Muhammad Ali

In odoo13 the `src_model` is deprecated instead of that it now using the `binding_model`.

**binding_model**: It is the target module where the wizard will appear when we click the action button.
**Example** - Suppose you want to open a wizard from `res.partner` the `binding_model` will be the `res.partner.`